# Creating DataTable from Protocol Buffer

Tags: python, datatable, protocol-buffers

Good evening everyone,

I am stuck and cannot figure out what to do.  I have an application where I am storing data from protocol buffer messages in a DataTable for each message.  To do this, I need to get the field names for each of the columns.  For the fields that are enums, I create another DataTable with those values and put all of these tables into a data set for a single message.  Below is my working code to do this:

```
def makeMessageTables(self, messageType):

        # Instance variable for the message DataSet
        self.messageDataSet = DataSet()

        ###################################################################
        # Create a table in the DataSet to hold the message structure.
        ###################################################################
        messageTable = DataTable()

        messageTable.TableName = 'messageTable'

        # Construct columns in the table to correspons with the message fields.
        messageFields = messageType.DESCRIPTOR.fields
        for field in messageFields:
            messageTable.Columns.Add(field.name)

        # Add the table to the DataSet
        self.messageDataSet.Tables.Add(messageTable)

        ###################################################################
        # Make a table for each field that has an enum type associated
        # with it.  The table has the display values and the storage 
        # values in it foe setting up the ComboBox in the DataGridView
        ###################################################################
        for field in messageFields:
            if field.enum_type != None:
                tableName = '{}_enumTable'.format(field.enum_type.name)
                enumTable = DataTable()
                enumTable.TableName = tableName;
                enumTable.Columns.Add('enumDisplay')
                enumTable.Columns.Add('enumValue')

                for value in field.enum_type.values:
                    newRow = enumTable.NewRow()
                    newRow['enumDisplay'] = value.name
                    newRow['enumValue'] = value.number
                    enumTable.Rows.Add(newRow)

                self.messageDataSet.Tables.Add(enumTable)
```

Now, today I hit a message that has sub-messages.  I want a separate table for each of the sub-messages.  The problem I am having is that I do not know how to break down the message to get the fields names and other information from the sub-messages.  I have provided a representative sample message like I am trying to deal with below.

```
message SystemOneStatusDetails
{
    required int32 field1 = 1;
        required int32 field1 = 1;
        required int32 field1 = 1;
        required int32 field1 = 1;
}

message SystemTwoStatusDetails
{
    required int32 field1 = 1;
        required int32 field1 = 1;
        required int32 field1 = 1;
        required int32 field1 = 1;
}

message StatusMessage
{
    repeated SystemOneStatusDetails sysOneStatus = 1;           

    repeated SystemTwoStatusDetails sysTwoStatus = 2;           
}
```

I am using IronPython 2.7 inside Visual Studio.

If anyone could lead me in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks,
Robert Hix

Answer (score 0):

I have only used protocol buffers in Java, so I can only give high-level hints.  Hopefully some one know more about Protocol buffers in python.

There will be a definition for each message and inside each message each field is defined. It is all very much like the proto file.

Here is the proto file I used:

```
message SystemOneStatusDetails
{
    required int32 field1 = 1;
    required int32 field2 = 2;
    required int32 field3 = 3;
    required int32 field4 = 4;
}

message SystemTwoStatusDetails
{
    required int32 field1 = 1;
    required int32 field2 = 2;
    required int32 field3 = 3;
    required int32 field4 = 4;
}

message StatusMessage
{
    repeated SystemOneStatusDetails sysOneStatus = 1;           

    repeated SystemTwoStatusDetails sysTwoStatus = 2;           
}
```

Following is the Field-Definition (used in Java):
[image]

---

You seem to writing a general purpose utility, So for future reference Protocol messages can be a lot more complicated e.g. messages can be defined in messages

```
message outer {
       message inner {
            ....
       } 

       required inner myInner = 1;
```

}

plus you can also have **extensions** to messages like:

```
message Message {
    extensions 100 to max;

    required uint64 A = 1;
    required string name = 2;
}

message Event {
    extensions 100 to max;

    required uint64 B = 1;
    required string eventName = 2;

/*      assert_p('LineFrameTree.FileDisplay_JTbl', 'Content', '[[A, 1, , UINT64, 123, 123], [name, 1, , STRING, aa, aa]]') */
}

message Note {
    required string text = 1;
}


extend Message { 
    optional Event ext = 101; 
    repeated Note notes = 103; 
}
```